# How to make a simple left join with criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a table of users, with user_id.

I'm fetching users like this:

```
    Criteria c = session.createCriteria(User.class);
```

now I have a table tickets with a foreign key to the users table. there is a column user_id

i want in my criteria to get all the users with ticket type X.

i tried something like this:

```
c.createAlias("ticket", "ticket");
c.add(Restrictions.ne("ticket.type", "X"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the createAlias method you can specify which join you need.

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(User.class)
                .createAlias("ticket", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
```

or

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(User.class, "user")
                .createAlias("user.ticket", "ticket", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
```